# Pytorch: How to concatenate lists within a tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, concatenation

I have a tensor of size `(2, b, h)` and I want to change it to the following size: `(b, 2*h)`, where the corresponding lists are concatenated, for example:

```py
a = torch.tensor([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 4, 4]],
                  [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [5, 5, 5]]])
```

I want:

```py
b = tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use permute first to change order of dimensions, then contiguous to prevent strides within the permuted tensor and finally use view to reshape the tensor.

```
b = a.permute(1,0,2).contiguous().view(a.shape[1],-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to concatenate tensors in pytorch, you can use the [torch.cat](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html?highlight=cat#torch.cat) function which concatenates tensors along a chosen axis.
In this example, you can do:

```py
a = torch.tensor([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 4, 4]],
                  [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [5, 5, 5]]])

b = torch.cat((a[0], a[1]), dim=1)

Out:
tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]])
```

Comment: Also doable. Might be harder to follow for the general case though. Furthermore, might be a bit slower than my proposition.